# Saving two columns on csv file after running two separate for loops

Tags: python, loops, csv, beautifulsoup, writer

I have a code below which scrapes web data using BeautifulSoup. I am using two different for loops to grab two different sets of data: `name` and `value`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ticker + '/key-statistics?p=' + ticker).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('yahoo_key_stats_grab.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['name', 'value'])

def yahoo_key_stats_grab(ticker):

    for stat in soup.find_all('span')[12:21]:
        name = stat.text
        print(name)
        csv_writer.writerow([name])

    for stat in soup.find_all('td', class_='Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)'):

        if len(str(stat.text)) > 6:
            break

        else:
            print(stat.text)


    csv_file.close()
```

If I run the code `yahoo_key_stats_grab('MIC')`, I get the following output: which is exactly what I want.

```
Market Cap (intraday)
Enterprise Value
Trailing P/E
Forward P/E
PEG Ratio (5 yr expected)
Price/Sales
Price/Book
Enterprise Value/Revenue
Enterprise Value/EBITDA
3.23B
6.8B
6.95
16.04
1.64
1.73
1.04
3.65
10.80
```

However, I would like to save the scraped data on a csv file with two columns `name` and `value`. I can get the name column, but I can't figure out how to add the second column `value` to the csv file.

```
name                             value

Market Cap (intraday)   

Enterprise Value    

Trailing P/E    

Forward P/E 

PEG Ratio (5 yr expected)   

Price/Sales 

Price/Book  

Enterprise Value/Revenue    

Enterprise Value/EBITDA
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns to csv files by passing an array to the csv.write() method.

Example:

```
    import csv

    data = [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"]

    csv_file = open('testfile.csv', 'w')

    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['name', 'value'])

    for row in data:
        csv_writer.writerow(data[0], data[1])

    csv_file.close()
```

Update: In your case, since you have two different for loops creating your data, you can store the first set of data in a list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ticker + '/key-statistics?p=' + ticker).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('yahoo_key_stats_grab.csv', 'w')

csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['name', 'value'])

def yahoo_key_stats_grab(ticker):
    names = []

    for stat in soup.find_all('span')[12:21]:
        names.append(stat.text)

    for stat in soup.find_all('td', class_='Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)'):

        if len(str(stat.text)) > 6:
            break

        else:
            csv_writer.writerow([names.pop(0), stat.text])
            # note that this will throw an exception if there
            # are a different number of names and stats!


    csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help. It works great as exactly I want. Can you please try to explain how the names.pop(0) work in the codes?

Comment: .pop() is a method for lists that removes an element from a list and returns that element (by default it removes the last element, so we call .pop(0) to remove the first element): https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best options but what will work is to append the values to a list in the for loops that you have running and then print out what you need using the values you collected. Something like:

```
field = []
value = []
for stat in soup.find_all('span')[12:21]:
    name = stat.text
    print(name)
    field.append(name)

for stat in soup.find_all('td', class_='Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)'):

    if len(str(stat.text)) > 6:
        break

    else:
        value.append(stat.text)
```

then print them out with a new for loop with csv_writer in a single line separated by whatever separator you want for the csv

Comment: Thanks for your input!